# Как сделать выпадающее меню в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте, нужно выпадающее меню с пунктом без ссылки. Объясняю: в `wordpress` понятно устроена структура меню, **но** для того чтобы сделать страницу, как-бы родителем для дочерних страниц, нужно ее создать, дочерним оставить её в родителя, а потом уже вставить в том же порядке в меню. Мне надо сделать чтобы этот родитель отображался в меню, пути соблюдались, **но** чтобы этой страницы в принципе не существовало, при переходе на нее кидало на 404, а вменю была бы заглушка типа `#`. Например: `Главная-О компании-О нас`, так вот страница "о компании" мне нужна только для реализации выпадающего меню и правильных путей на сайте (breadcrumbs). Как мне это сделать? Час бьюсь не могу разобраться, без правок `php` это не предусмотрено данной CMS?

Comment: Нет ничего проще. Создайте пункт меню "О компании" как произвольную ссылку на #,

Comment: @KAGGDesign да, но страница "О компании" то есть, она ведь является родителем для "о нас" и в урле если прописать путь до нее, то она отображается, как её скрыть в таком случае?

Comment: Не надо вообще создавать страницу О компании, сделайте О нас дочкой Главной

Comment: @KAGGDesign мне как раз это не нужно.

Comment: Тогда непонятно, что вам нужно. Структура меню к отношениям родитель-потомок отношения не имеет.

Comment: И кидать на 404 - ОЧЕНЬ плохое решение для SEO.

Comment: @KAGGDesign мне критично чтобы пути были именно такие какие я указал, как в принципе вообще такое можно сделать? Необязательно на 404, мне желательно вообще её скрыть.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68797/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-).